# Processing very large dataset in real time in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I'm trying to understand how to architect a big data solution. I have historic data of 400TB of data and every hour 1GB of data is getting inserted.

Since data is confidential, I'm describing sample scenario, Data contains information of all activities in a bank branch. With every hour, when new data is inserted(no updation) into hdfs, I need to find how many loans closed, loans created,accounts expired, etc ( around 1000 analytics to be performed). Analytics involve processing entire 400TB of data.

I was plan was to use hadoop + spark. But I'm being suggested to use HBase. Reading through all the documents, I'm not able to find a clear advantage.

What is the best way to go for data which will grow to 600TB
1. MR for analytics and impala/hive for query
2. Spark for analytics and query
3. HBase + MR for analytics and query

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spark is a distributed computation framework, HBase is a no-sql database. It's seems nonsensical to me to choose one over the other.

Comment: @DanielDarabos Yes I understand.. I'm trying to figure out what is the advantage of using HBase over HDFS. Is HBase good when operation on entire dataset needs to be performed

Comment: I think the advantage of HBase would be the support for updates. Since you have no updates, what is the argument in favor of HBase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About HBase:**

HBase is a database that is build over HDFS. HBase uses HDFS to store data. 
Basically, HBase will allow you to update records, have versioning and deletion of single records. HDFS does not support file updates, so HBase is introducing something you can consider "virtual" operations, and merge data from multiple sources (original files, delete markers) when you are asking it for data. Also, HBase as key-value store is creating indices to support selecting by key.

**Your problem:**

Choosing the technology in such situations you should look into what you are going to do with the data: Single query on Impala (with Avro schema) can be much faster than MapReduce (not to mention Spark). Spark will be faster in batch jobs, when there is caching involved.

You are probably familiar with Lambda architecture, if not, take a look into it. For what I can tell you now, the third option you mentioned (HBase and MR only) won't be good. I did not try Impala + HBase, so I can't say anything about performance, but HDFS (plain files) + Spark + Impala (with Avro), worked for me: Spark was doing reports for pre-defined queries (after that, data was stored in objectFiles - not human-readable, but very fast), Impala for custom queries.

Hope it helps at least a little.

Comment: Thanks @szefuf.. After lot of reading I'm also planning to go with spark + impala + hbase(for user info retrieval as I expect 100 million users are present). I'm curious to know more about objectFiles?

Comment: ObjectFiles are something like paging in RAM. It's not serialized to human-readable form, but it allows to retrieve RDD from hard drive very fast. This mechnism is also used when RDD is cached, but RAM memory is not enough to accomodate whole RDD (then part is stored on hard drive - you can see it in Spark UI). I have used it to store intermediete reports from over two months - thanks to this If anyone wanted to retrieve and aggregate historical data it could be done in seconds.
Just save it using RDD.saveAsObjectFile("") and read as sc.objectFile(""):RDD.